# A weird sentence with subjunctive-mood

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I saw a weird sentence, which goes below:

***Even though you wouldn't be looking for employment right now, it still wouldn't hurt for you to prepare much like you would if you were looking for a job.***

I think it uses subjunctive mood, but I don't get why "much like" is used here and how the "if" clause works. It looks like a wrong sentence but Grammarly tells me it has no error.
Can anyone help me break this sentence down? Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140083/discussion-on-question-by-lingfeng-xiang-a-weird-sentence-with-subjunctive-mood).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'much like' means 'in the same way as'.

It's not a very good sentence, the first subjunctive might be used in colloquial speech. I prefer

> Even though you <strike>wouldn't be</strike> **aren't** looking for employment right now, it still wouldn't hurt for you to prepare *[comma]***,** much like you would if you were [actually] looking for a job."

I hope the edit gives more sense to the 'if' clause. If you were looking for a job, you would be preparing. You aren't looking for a job, but it still won't hurt to act as though you *are*.

Comment: The source is https://github.com/iamyuanchung/TOEFL-QA/blob/master/data/train/tpo_6-conversation_1_4. From the context you will see that the speaker is talking to a student who is not looking for a job (as he is studying) and talking about going to a career fair. The "would not be" is, in context, correct as there is a hidden "if" clause -- *Even though, **in your case, if you were to go**, you wouldn't be looking for a job...*

Comment: Thank you! I got it!